# Difference between cat and '>' to zero out a file

Tags: io-redirection, cat

Are these two commands any different on how they go about zero-ing out files? Is the latter a shorter way of doing the former? What is happening behind the scenes?

Both

```
$ cat /dev/null > file.txt

$ > file.txt
```

yield

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel  0 May 18 10:33 file.txt
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`cat /dev/null > file.txt` is a [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Basically `cat /dev/null` simply results in `cat` outputting nothing. Yes it works, but it's frowned upon by many because it results in invoking an external process that is not necessary.
It's one of those things that is common simply because it's common.

Using just `> file.txt` will work on most shells, but it's not completely portable. If you want completely portable, the following are good alternatives:

```
true > file.txt
: > file.txt
```

Both `:` and `true` output no data, and are shell builtins (whereas `cat` is an external utility), thus they are lighter and more 'proper'.

Update:

As tylerl mentioned in his comment, there is also the `>| file.txt` syntax.

Most shells have a setting which will prevent them from truncating an existing file via `>`. You must use `>|` instead. This is to prevent human error when you really meant to append with `>>`. You can turn the behavior on with `set -C`.

So with this, I think the simplest, most proper, and portable method of truncating a file would be:

```
:>| file.txt
```

Comment: The colon command [is defined in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/colon.html). It is a null operation that exists to expand commandline args.

Comment: @kojiro actually it's not implementation specific. POSIX very explicitly states that `true` is a shell builtin.

Comment: LOL, "cat abuse"

Comment: @kojiro `:` is also mandated by POSIX to be built-in, and in fact is different from `true` in that it is considered a ["special" built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14).

Comment: @jw013 I think "special" in the context on that page means it's a "special utility", not a "special built-in". At least I don't see it mentioning any difference between a special built-in and a non-special built-in.

Comment: @Patrick The phrase "special utility" does not appear anywhere. The link I gave explains the difference between a special built-in and a regular built-in: *however, the special built-in utilities described here differ from regular built-in utilities in two respects: ...* What do you mean by special utility?

Comment: don't forget about *noclobber*. `>| file` is a more explicit truncate.

Comment: So to clear a file, you just have to apply the right smiley :>

Comment: `> file` doesn't work in `csh`, `tcsh`, `fish` or `zsh` (except in sh/ksh emulation) so I wouldn't say it works in most shells. It works in most shells of the Bourne and rc families.

Comment: No `true` is not required to be builtin and it traditionally wasn't. `:` is built in all the shells of the Bourne family. `:` is a special builtin per POSIX (so `: > file` will exit the shell for instance if `file` can't be open for writing in POSIX shells) and `true` is not. POSIX even mentions that `:` may be more _efficient_ than `true` on some systems.

Comment: No `ksh` _hasn't that by default_. The POSIX spec is based on `ksh`, so if it was in `ksh`, it would be the case in all POSIX shells. `set -o noclobber` aka `set -C` and `>|` are POSIX but not Bourne nor csh, tcsh, rc, es, fish, so you can't really say it's portable.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas What do you make of 1.c in [Command Search and Execution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01)? The way I interpret it, `true` must bypass `PATH` lookup and unless a shell hardcodes a fixed path to an external `true` binary, the only way it can meet that requirement is to make the listed utilities built-in.

Comment: @jw013, in practice, all the POSIX shells I know have `true` builtin anyway and like you I don't see the point of executing a hardcoded true, but think of busybox as a possible counter-example. Note that very few shells implement that section of the spec (they generally still run `[` or `echo` for instance even if they're not found in `$PATH`). I find it strange that `false`, `true` are included in that list and not `type`.

Answer (score 25):

#### In terms of portability:

```
                      Bourne POSIX  zsh    csh/tcsh  rc/es  fish
> file                Y      Y      N(1)   N(1)      N      N
: > file              N/Y(2) Y(3)   Y      Y(4)      N(5)   N(5)
true > file           Y(5)   Y      Y      Y(5)      Y(5)   Y(5)
cat /dev/null > file  Y(5)   Y      Y(5)   Y(5)      Y(5)   Y(5)
eval > file           Y(3,8) Y(3)   Y      Y(6)      Y      Y
cp /dev/null file (7) Y(5)   Y      Y(5)   Y(5)      Y(5)   Y(5)
printf '' > file      Y(5)   Y      Y      Y(5)      Y(5)   Y
```

Notes:

1. except in `sh` or `ksh` emulation, for redirections without a command, in zsh, a default command is assumed (a pager for stdin redirection only, `cat` otherwise), that can be tuned with the NULLCMD and READNULLCMD variables. That's inspired from the similar feature in `(t)csh`
2. Redirections were initially not performed for `:` in UnixV7 as `:` was interpreted half-way between a comment leader and a null command. Later they were and like for all builtins, if the redirection fails, that exits the shell.
3. `:` and `eval` being special built-ins, if the redirection fails, that exits the shell (`bash` only does that in POSIX mode).
4. Interestingly, in `(t)csh`, that's defining a null label (for `goto`), so `goto ''` there would branch there. If the redirection fails, that exits the shell.
5. Unless/if the corresponding command is available in `$PATH` (`:` generally isn't; `true`, `cat`, `cp` and `printf` generally are (POSIX requires them)).
6. If the redirection fails, that exits the shell.
7. If `file` is a symlink to an non-existing file however, some `cp` implementations like GNU's will refuse to create it.
8. The initial versions of the Bourne shell [didn't support redirecting builtins though](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/index.html)

#### In terms of legibility:

(this section is highly subjective)

- `> file`. That `>` looks too much like a prompt or a comment. Also the question I'll ask when reading that (and most shells will complain about the same) is *what output exactly are you redirecting?*.
- `: > file`. `:` is known as the no-op command. So that reads straight away as generating an empty file. However, here again, that `:` can easily be missed and/or seen as a prompt.
- `true > file`: *what has boolean to do with redirection or file content? What is meant here?* is the first thing that comes to my mind when I read that.
- `cat /dev/null > file`. *Concatenate `/dev/null` into `file`?* `cat` being often seen as the command to dump the content of the file, that can still make sense: *dump the content of **the** empty file into `file`*, a bit like a convoluted way to say `cp /dev/null file` but still understandable.
- `cp /dev/null file`. Copies the content of *the empty file* to `file`. Makes sense, though someone not knowing how `cp` is meant to do by default might think you're trying to make `file` a `null` device as well.
- `eval > file` or `eval '' > file`. Runs nothing and redirects its output to a `file`. Makes sense to me. Strange that it's not a common idiom.
- `printf '' > file`: explicitly *prints* nothing into a file. The one that makes most sense to me.

#### In terms of performance

The difference is going to be whether we're using a shell builtin or not. If not, a process has to be forked, the command loaded and executed.

`eval` is guaranteed to be built in all shells. `:` is built-in wherever it's available (Bourne/csh likes). `true` is builtin in Bourne-like shells only.

`printf` is built-in most modern Bourne-like shells and `fish`.

`cp` and `cat` generally are not built-in.

Now `cp /dev/null file` does not invoke shell redirections, so things like:

```
find . -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

are going to be more efficient than:

```
find . -exec sh -c '> "$1"' sh {} \;
```

(though not necessarily than:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'for f do : > "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

).

#### Personally

Personally, I use `: > file` in Bourne-like shells, and don't use anything other than Bourne-like shells these days.

Comment: What about `dd of=file count=0`?

Comment: @kojiro, With some implementations of `dd` (like Solaris 10's at least), `count=0` is ignored. `dd if=/dev/null of=file` would be more portable. In any case, that's independent from the shell.

Comment: OK, but it's no less deserving of inclusion than `cp /dev/null file`, right?

Comment: @kojiro, `cp /dev/null file` is a common idiom. I'm limiting to those, the point is not of listing all the possible ways.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at `truncate`, which does exactly that: truncate a file.

For example:

```
truncate --size 0 file.txt
```

This is probably slower than using `true > file.txt`.

My main point however is: `truncate` is intended for truncating files, while using > has the side effect of truncating a file.

Comment: Truncate is nice when you want to truncate a file to something other than 0. That said, *even without a shell* is a strange statement: can you describe a context where `truncate` would be available, but neither `>` nor `unistd` C libraries would be available?

Comment: Not really. There is probably a more elegant solution for every script or programming language available.

Comment: `truncate` is a FreeBSD utility, relatively recently (2008) added to the GNU coreutils (though the `--size` GNU long option style is GNU specific), so it's not available in non-GNU-or-FreeBSD systems, and it's not available in older GNU systems, I wouldn't say it's portable. `cp /dev/null file` would work without a shell redirection and would be more portable.

Comment: Okay, I will remove that portability comment. Though your definition of recent seems to differ.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends a bit on what `file.txt` is, and how process write to it!

I'll cite a common use case : you have a growing logfile called `file.txt`, and want to rotate it.

Therefore you copy, for example, `file.txt` into `file.txt.save`, then truncate `file.txt`.

In this scenario, *IF* the file is not opened by `another_process` (ex: `another_process` could be a program outputting to that file, for example a program logging something), then your 2 proposals are equivalent, and both work well (but the 2nd is prefered as the first "cat /dev/null > file.txt" is a Useless Use of Cat and also opens and reads /dev/null).

**But** the real trouble would be if the `other_process` is still active, and still has an open handle going to the file.txt.

Then, 2 main cases arise, depending on how `other process` opened the file :

- If `other_process` opens it in the normal way, then the handle will be still pointing to the former location in the file, for example at offset 1200 bytes. The next write will therefore start at offset 1200, and thus you'll have again a file of 1200bytes (+ whatever other_process wrote), with 1200 leading null characters! **Not what you want**, I presume.
- If `other_process` opened `file.txt` in "append mode", then each time it writes, the pointer will actively seek to the end of the file. Therefore, when you truncate it, it will "seek" until byte 0, and you won't have the bad side effect! **This is what you want** (... usually!)

Note that this means you need, when you truncate a file, to make sure that all `other_process` still writing to that location have opened it in the "append" mode. Otherwise you'll need to stop those `other_process`, and start them again, so they start pointing at the beginning of the file instead of the former location.

References : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16720582/1841533 for a cleaner explanation, and a nice short example of difference between normal and append mode logging at https://stackoverflow.com/a/984761/1841533

Comment: Very little of this answer actually is relevant to or answers the question. The difference between a `cat /dev/null > file` and a `> file` is a `cat /dev/null` and that makes no difference to the file.

Comment: @jw013: True! But I just wanted to take the question's opportunity to re-state the "what you want/not what you want" information, as it's not very well known, and could hit hard someone trying to rotate logs (a common case where you want to truncate a file).

Comment: There is a time and a place for everything. Your information may be useful in some other context but it does not belong here - you should find a more appropriate place for it because nobody trying to rotate logs is going to look in this completely unrelated redirection question. Here your answer is the equivalent of a digital weed, just as an otherwise useful pumpkin plant in the middle of a cornfield would be considered a weed.

Answer (score 1):

I like this and use it often because it looks cleaner and not like somebody hit the return key by accident:

```
echo -n "" > file.txt
```

Should be a built-in too?

Comment: There are many ways to zero-out a file.  I think KM. was only interested in understanding the difference between the two methods shown in the question.

Comment: Many `echo` implementations don't support `-n` (and would output `-n<SPC><NL>` here. `printf '' > file.txt` would be more portable (at least across modern/POSIX systems).