# How to delete huge files from linux

Tags: lsof, deleted-files

I've been facing an issue that while using `lsof | grep deleted` command, I got the following result:

```
sendmail  11633  smmsp    3uW     REG                8,7    329818112    8119977 /var/spool/clientmqueue/dft4CCv1K5011633 (deleted)
tcpdump   11759   pcap    4w      REG                8,7 446113333248   41846283 /var/kalsym/logs/CAPTimedOUT_monitor/capAbort_2015-05-12_17-57-01.pcap (deleted)
```

Then I follow this procedure.

```
cd /proc/11759/fd
> /proc/11759/fd/4
```

but after that, no effect has been observed on `/var` size. I searched a lot on the Internet regarding this issue and tried all possible ways, but in vain. Please suggest me the way to overcome this issue.

Comment: You can just do `kill 11759`.  Or how about `truncate -s0 /proc/11759/fd/4`?

Answer (score 4):

**You need to kill the process in order to free up the disk space**. In future you can truncate the file using

```
    echo "" > file_name
```

instead of deleting the file, if the file is being used by any running process.

Comment: `echo ""` does write a newline to the file. To truncate it use `:> <file>` or `echo -n > <file>` (if supported).

Answer (score -1):

```
cat /dev/null > /proc/PID/fd/4
```

Answer (score -2):

This will also clear the contents of a file

```
cp /dev/null filename
```

Comment: No it won't.  It will update the timestamp on the file, but will leave the contents unaltered.  It will create an emtpy file if there was not one there already though

Comment: Eric is correct. Touch will not clear the contents of the file. My bad.

Comment: Still not quite, that would try to execute `filename` and redirect it's `stdin` to be from `/dev/null`.  You can look at the comment from Marco to see an example of how to use redirection to do this (it works by running an "empty" command `:` and redirecting the output of that into the file)

Comment: Refer to [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130971/difference-between-cat-and-to-zero-out-a-file)Difference between cat and '>' to zero out a file Answers from Patrick and Stéphane Chazelas