# When creating an empty file, why might one prefer 'touch file' over ': >> file'?

Tags: shell, files, touch

Never realized that you could do this until just now:

```
: >> file
```

It seems to be functionally similar to:

```
touch file
```

Is there a reason why most resources seem to prefer touch over this shell builtin?

Comment: The short form may be shell related, while touch is a standalone command. Hence the short form depends on which shell you use (and people do have strong preferences in this area) as maybe not all of them provide the shortcut. `touch` being standalone will work the same way whatever should you use.

Comment: Related [What is the difference between touch file and > file](https://askubuntu.com/q/831414/283843) on AU.

Comment: The first example should be edited to `: >> file` or even `>> file`, so that they have the same effect, i.e. NOT destroying the contents of file.

Comment: `touch` primarily updates the mtime. It does not empty an existing file unlike `>`.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but related, and has good info: [Difference between cat and '>' to zero out a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/130971/4358)

Comment: Neither command "creates an empty file"; they only have this result if the file does not yet exist. To guarantee an empty file, you need `> file`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You don't even need to use `:`; you can just `> file` (at least in `bash`; other shells may behave differently).

In practical terms, there is no real difference here (though the minuscule overhead of calling out to `/bin/touch` is a thing).

`touch`, however, can also be used to modify the timestamps on a file that already exists without changing or erasing the contents; further, `> file` will blow out any `file` that already exists.  This can be worked around by instead using `>> file`.

One other difference with `touch` is that you can have it create (or update the timestamp on) multiple files at once (e.g. `touch foo bar baz quux`) with a more succinct syntax than with redirection, where each file needs its own redirection (e.g. `>foo >bar >baz >quux`).

Using `touch`:

```
$ touch foo; stat -x foo; sleep 2; touch foo; stat -x foo
  File: "foo"
  Size: 0            FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (991148597/redacted)  Gid: (1640268302/redacted)
Device: 1,5   Inode: 8597208698    Links: 1
Access: Fri May 25 10:55:19 2018
Modify: Fri May 25 10:55:19 2018
Change: Fri May 25 10:55:19 2018
  File: "foo"
  Size: 0            FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (991148597/redacted)  Gid: (1640268302/redacted)
Device: 1,5   Inode: 8597208698    Links: 1
Access: Fri May 25 10:55:21 2018
Modify: Fri May 25 10:55:21 2018
Change: Fri May 25 10:55:21 2018
```

Using redirection:

```
$ > foo; stat -x foo; sleep 2; >> foo; stat -x foo
  File: "foo"
  Size: 0            FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (991148597/redacted)  Gid: (1640268302/redacted)
Device: 1,5   Inode: 8597208698    Links: 1
Access: Fri May 25 10:55:21 2018
Modify: Fri May 25 10:56:25 2018
Change: Fri May 25 10:56:25 2018
  File: "foo"
  Size: 0            FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (991148597/redacted)  Gid: (1640268302/redacted)
Device: 1,5   Inode: 8597208698    Links: 1
Access: Fri May 25 10:55:21 2018
Modify: Fri May 25 10:56:25 2018
Change: Fri May 25 10:56:25 2018
```

Comment: It seems like `>> file` will not update the modify time.  Not what OP is looking for but just wanted to point out it doesn't seem to be a complete alternative to touch.

Comment: Since the question doesn't specify a particular shell. It might be good to point out that `> file` in zsh is equivalent to `cat > file`, not `: > file`.

Comment: Also, tcsh allows `: > file`, but errs on `> file`. Maybe the equivalence of `> file` to `: > file` is limited to the bourne shell and bash?

Comment: +1 for thoroughness, however note that on several mainstream shells (I would even guess all or most shells because the most simple implementation would naturally cause this to work as a side-effect), you can touch multiple files using shell redirection: `: >foo >bar` or `: >>foo >>bar` will touch both `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Only to be pedantic because of the context of the actual question here, but `: >foo >bar` will not _`touch`_ the files; it will redirect the (null) output of `:` _into_ the files.  `touch` would touch the files.  (:

Answer (score 32):

Because you can `touch` multiple files at one go without typing any extra special characters. That includes stuff like brace expansion, e.g. `touch file{1,2,3,4}`.

Another issue is that when you're writing a tutorial, it's rather important to realize that your readers probably aren't very well-versed in the subject. A simple command can be much more understandable than some weird-looking combination of non-letter characters. I would expect there are a number of casual shell users who don't know what `:` is, for the simple reason that it doesn't really *do* anything. Similarly for a plain `> foo` without a command: even if you know what a redirection is, a redirection *without a source* may be unintuitive.

Also, here on unix.se we often write command samples with a leading dollar sign to indicate the prompt. Special characters at the start of the line might be confused with that. (Note that there are systems and shells that use `>` as part of the default prompt.)

Comment: And if the command is not completely understood, there's always "man touch".  I doubt that "man : > file" would return anything useful :-)  Also WRT prompts, some (perhaps most) allow you to set the prompt to be anything you like.  Mine shows system name (because I use a lot of remote xterms) and current directory, and is set to different colors for different systems.

Comment: @jamesqf, yep. Now, of course there's also `help :` or whatever your shell has for documentation. But that requires recognizing `:` as a command in itself, remembering that not everything has a man page, and finally, being able to find `:` in the documentation. The last part can be quite difficult. :D

Comment: @jamesqf, and yeah, I mostly meant the final character of the default prompt.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the *intuition* and not-being-an-obscure-construct aspects.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Yeah.  Finding colons in documentation isn't that difficult: finding the one that's not just punctuation is a different matter :-)

Comment: @jamesqf actually it's very easy once you know that commands are usually listed in manual pages with several spaces before them, so e.g. `  :` (two spaces and a colon) will immediately match the relevant description in bash(1).

Answer (score 18):

Well, for me, the primary reason is readability. With `touch file` you know what's going on, even someone not quite educated in shell scripting knows what's going on. And if not, it's easy to do `man touch` and see this:

> `A FILE argument that does not exist is created empty`

With the cryptic stuff such as `:` and `>`, it's more difficult to know what's going on, and as there's no real advantage, there's no need to use that.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine that you are in search of one of your old shell scripts of which you only remember that some marker file in /tmp is being created.
It's easy to grep all your *.sh files for the word "touch". Grepping for a colon instead will yield many false positives if you don't know which exact filename to search for.